Switch with supply but no load
I’ve been replacing the old switches and sockets in my home with new Hager units. I found a fused spur switch in the cupboard where my hot water tank and boiler wiring is located. Live and neutral wires are connected to the supply side of the switch (the wire disappears behind the water tank so not sure where it’s going), but nothing is connected to the load side of the switch. And there’s no fuse installed in the switch. Am I right in thinking this switch does nothing? Why would it have even be wired like this?

Was used at one time, but stuff was changed since.  Make sure power is off to it.  You will have a bad day if power is still on, and you touch live/neutral.

Yeah I’ve switched off all the breakers before touching anything. And I’m not messing with any wiring, I’m only changing the face plates. I was just curious as to what was going on. Thanks for the reply.

Have you considered that it might have been wired for a device that was subsequently removed, or left as a future provision that simply hasn't been used?
